# Como utilizar el ciclo do_while

Tags: php, base-de-datos, bucles, codeigniter-3

tengo una duda o inquietud. Tengo que hacer una consulta en la base de datos y comprobar si el campo está vacio, insertar un número. Estoy usando un ciclo do_while y la idea es que se me repita la consulta las veces que sea necesaria hasta que encuentre el campo vacio, este es el código que tengo por el momento:

```
public function consultar($id)
{
    $resultado = $this->Model_login->traerPrueba($id);

    do {
            $comprobar = $this->Model_login->traerPrueba($resultado->id_izquierda);
            $resultado = $comprobar->id;
            echo " " . $resultado . "";
    } while (!empty($resultado->id_izquierda));

    echo "si termina si funciona acá ".$resultado->id;
}
```

y este es el modelo que me lo consulta:

```
public function traerPrueba($id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT id, id_papa_pago, id_izquierda ,nombre,apellido1
    FROM master_usuarios
    WHERE id= ?";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql,[$id]);

    return $query->row();
}
```

el error que tengo, es que me consulta una sola vez. Me trae el primer echo y de paso me rompe el ciclo. Pero según mi base de dato, el ciclo se tiene que romper después de la tercera consulta que hay un campo vacio.

Pregunta editada:
Esta es la consulta que me trae la base de datos si el $id le doy un valor de 7

[image: consulta con id = 7]

el campo no está vacio, entonces tendria que repetirse pero con el valor que aparece en id_izquiera que es 10701

[image: Aqui es donde se cancela]

pero en vez de seguir con el ciclo, termina y no sigue consultando hasta encontrar id_izquierdo = (null) o vacio

Comment: por que usas do while cuando puede usar foreach o while directamente???

Comment: que contiene $resultado?

Comment: Resultado contiene la consulta que se hizo en la base de dato, los campos perteneciente al usuario, tanto como nombre, apellido, y el campo a verificar que es id_izquierdo.

Me dijeron que usara do_while, pero si puedo usar directamente el while como solución, acepto la respuesta, desde que funcione

Comment: puedes agregar la estructura de las columnas no me queda claro tu comentario... edita la pregunta.

Comment: anexé 2 imagenes con un ejemplo de lo que quiero, pero al usarlo con el ciclo while o do_while

Comment: ok estube mirando tu scrip y lo que agregaste y la verdad el codigo no tiene lo mas minimo que ver con lo que esperas hacer; por ejemplo cuando usas `while`, `foreach` o `do...while` son ciclos para iterar objetos o array; en este caso `!empty($resultado->id_izquierda)` dentro del do while es un error. tengo una respuesta para este primer punto...

Comment: pero ... tu aceberas querer hacer un insert y la verdad no veo ningun insert de ningun tipo... si te doy una respuesta no podre incluir el insert ya que no se que es lo que pretendes realmente.

Comment: ***comprobar si el campo está vacio, insertar un número.*** cual campo? cual insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias al comentario de ArcanisGK507 me hizo caer en cuenta en algo, y por el momento queria nada más la consulta. Tenia mal el orden y estaba volviendo a consultar y luego si imprimia el mensaje, era primero imprimir el mensaje y luego si reemplazar la variable para que me repitiera el ciclo y así quedó

```
        do {
            print_r($resultado);
            $resultado = $this->Model_login->traerPrueba($resultado->id_izquierda);
        } while ($resultado != null);

        print_r($resultado);
```

Answer (score 1):

para el modelo que locaste deberia ser algo asi:

```php
public function consultar($id)
{
    $resultado = $this->Model_login->traerPrueba($id);

    foreach($resultado as $column => $data){ //iteramos las columnas del row que retorna traerPrueba
       if(empty($resultado->id_izquierda) || $resultado->id_izquierda == null || $resultado->id_izquierda =='')//validamos si encontramos esta columnas si esta vacia
       {
           // aqui debes hacer el insert
       
       }

    }
}
```

como veras estoy usando un [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.foreach.php) y el [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty)